# What is the value of $i^i$?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

I understand that when you raise any number $x$ to a power, you multiply $x$ by itself the number of times indicated in the power. However, what happens when $i^i$ is performed? How can a number be multiplied an imaginary amount of times? Wolfram Alpha says that it is equal to $e^{{-\pi}/{2}}$, but how would you arrive at that answer? Any response will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$? If so, start by putting in $x=\pi/2$.

Comment: That kind of looks like DeMoivre's Theorem, but what exactly happens?

Comment: joe, why not try it, and see?

Comment: As noted in particular by L.F., Argon and ncmathsadist, the answer depends on the branch of the complex logarithm you choose to work with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$i^i = e^{i\log i} = e^{i(\log |i|+i\arg i)} = e^{i(i\arg i)} = e^{-\arg i} = e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}+2 \pi k} \qquad k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: There is an extra $i$ in your last term.

Comment: You seem to say that $\arg i=\pi/2+2\pi ik$. I think it is rather $\pi/2+2\pi k$.

Comment: I have always seen everywhere $\arg (re^{i\theta})=\theta +2k\pi$ (when $r>0$ and $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$).

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the complex numbers you consider an exponential of a base other than $e$, such as $z^x$, to be:
$$z^x := e^{x\log z }$$
So we have:
$$i^i = e^{i\log i}$$
But $\log i = i\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n\right)$, so we have 
$$i^i = e^{ii(\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n)} = e^{\frac{-\pi}{2} + 2\pi n} ~~~~~~~~~~ n\in \Bbb{Z}$$
Taking $n=0$ gives the value that Wolfram Alpha gave you.

Comment: I think it should be mentioned that $e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}$ is the *principal value* of the expression, $i^i$ can take infinitely many real values.

Comment: Yes, caveat emptor.

Comment: One must be careful about complex powers; this is a branch-of-the-log consideration.

Comment: Yes, as L.F. said, log i can produce an infinite number of values, and is only a function upon selecting a branch $i(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi n). $ $e^{-\pi/2}$ is the principal value with $n=0$.

Answer (score -1):

For example, $$i^i=(\cos(\pi/2)+i\sin(\pi/2))^i=e^{i(i\pi/2)}=e^{-\pi/2}$$

Comment: No.........   This does not work.

Comment: @ncmathsadist: Why not? Just curious.

Comment: It is not well-defined.  The map $z \mapsto z^i$ needs to be defined as $z \mapsto e^{i\log(z)}$.   Since the complex exponential is periodic, what's the meaning of $\log$?

Comment: @ncmathsadist: I see; you're saying it is essentially because $\sin$ is periodic? I mean, we can take $5\pi/2$ and get a different answer?

Comment: A periodic function is not 1-1.  A function must by 1-1 to possess an inverse.  You achieve this with the trig functions by pruning the domain.  The same thing must be done in complex analysis with the log function.

Comment: Lol @Downvoter: you are late to the show :-P

Answer (score -1):

for any complex number $z\in \mathbb C$ it can be written as $z=x+iy$ or in the polar form $z=re^{i\theta}$ where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\theta=\arctan(\frac{y}{x})$, so in particular $i=0+i1$ which implies that $r=1$ and $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ Thus, $$i=e^{\frac{\pi i}{2}}$$ which implies that $$i^i=(e^{\frac{\pi i}{2}})^i=e^{\frac{-\pi }{2}}.$$

Comment: @Argon I know that, but it is still true, the argument of $i$ is $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: @Argon I understand what you mean, but may be I should've just written that $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ without trying to explain it more.